# WordPress Loopcounting

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, loops, if-statement

Having a little issue at the moment, I'm trying to insert divs into a loop depending on how many posts there are.

So if there are only 2 posts out of a total 9 available slots I want 7 Divs with No post inside to show...

The problem I'm having is that I have this code at the moment:

```
<?php $nopost = '<div class="noPost">No post</div>' ?>

<?php $counter = 1; $counter++ ?>

<?php
    if($counter == 1) {
        echo str_repeat($nopost, 8);
    }
    elseif($counter == 2) {
        echo str_repeat($nopost, 7);
    } 
?>
```

Problem is, is that the loop will count, 1 and 2 not total of 2 so it will output 15 divs instead of what I want which is in the statement.

I'm really not sure how to go about this one Ive spent the past hour faffing around and figured I'd ask the pro's lol.

Live example of what I mean, http://thefinishedbox.com

Comment: There is no loop in this code anywhere. All you're doing is setting $counter to 2 regardless of how many posts there are. You need to initialize $counter before the WordPress loop begins, increment it inside the loop, and check its final value after the end of the loop.

Comment: The code is inside the wordpress loop, but I think i get what you mean, I'm not sure what to do about it, any ideas?

Comment: Yea I did that before, this is an alternate version and it made no difference.

Comment: I just put it outside the loop once again and its working better, though the only problem is, it's inserting it after the first post.

Comment: there is an error : `<?php $counter = 1; $counter++ ?>` you are increasing $counter by 1, but it's not inside of any loop (*while* or *for*) and also you forgot semi-colon at end of the `$counter++` . Because of this, $counter will return 2 , always.

Comment: Also, if you don't have do this with PHP , you can set a background image (like this : http://images.thefinishedbox.com/str/nopost.png) and you can overwrite if there is any content.

Comment: @eEray Alakese, how would I overwrite with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answser without seeing the exact code, but you need to put the counter initialization outside of the loop, then put the counter incrementing and the printing of the results inside the loop. Again, hard to say without seeing the loop.